# SQL insert multiple rows, foreach from one submit

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[this image explain what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBl0c.png)I am having trouble using PDO to insert multiple inputs records into a database. This code for foreach successfully add but only single record for one row in table, it didn't add all records rows. This is my code:

Html code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-name="cont-table">
```

```
      <tr>


        <th class="text-center"> م </th>



        <th class="text-center"> اسم الصنف </th>



        <th class="text-center"> الوحدة </th>




        <th class="text-center"> الكمية </th>



        <th class="text-center"> سعر الوحدة </th>



        <th class="text-center"> العام المالي </th>



        <th class="text-center"> إجمالي قيمة الصنف </th>



      </tr>



    </thead>



    <tr>



      <td></td>



      <td><span id="snum">1.</span></td>



      <td><!--<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name[]"/>!-->




        <select class="select" id="first_name" name="items[]">
```

query("SELECT first_name6 FROM item");



//$stmt = $pdo->execute();



while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {



echo "" . $row['first_name6'] . "";



}



?>

```
        </select></td>



      <td><!--<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name[]"/>!-->




        <select class="select" id="last_name" name="units[]">
```

query("SELECT first_name7 FROM unit");



//$stmt = $pdo->execute();



while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {



echo "" . $row['first_name7'] . "";



}



?>
            



 



     
          !-->

            

 query("SELECT first_name8 FROM financial");



//$stmt = $pdo->execute();



while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {



echo "" . $row['first_name8'] . "";



}



?>

```
        </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="total" name="totals[]" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="add_row"  type="button" class="delete btn btn-default pull-right">مسح</button>
  <button id="add_row" style="margin-right:5px;" type="button" class="addmore btn btn-default pull-right">اضاف صنف</button>

</form>
```

php code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['set-cont'])) {



   foreach ($_POST['items'] as $key => $value)  {



            $items = $_POST["items"][$key];



            $units = $_POST["units"][$key];



            $qtys = $_POST["qtys"][$key];



            $unitno = $_POST["unitno"][$key];



            $financials = $_POST["financials"][$key];



            $totals = $_POST["totals"][$key];



        try {



            $db = DB();



            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_contract (items, units,
```

qtys, unitno, financials, totals)

VALUES(:items,:units,:qtys,:unitno,:financials,:totals)");

```
            $query->bindParam("items", $items, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $query->bindParam("units", $units, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $query->bindParam("qtys", $qtys, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $query->bindParam("unitno", $unitno, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $query->bindParam("financials", $financials, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $query->bindParam("totals", $totals, PDO::PARAM_STR);



            $query->execute();



        } catch (PDOException $e) {



           exit($e->getMessage());



        }


    }



}
```

Comment: none of your `<select>`'s contain `<option>`'s. I don't know how you're populating those. and where are you using `$value`?

Comment: Any error messages (sql in particular)? Have you tried to do basic debugging, such as printing out `$items` and the other variables? Btw, you should not prepare the insert statement every time, it is enough to do this only once, just bind different parameters to it every time. This is the whole point of the prepared statements.

Comment: my selects using options but i didn't write it, tell me where i can insert $value .. im sorry im begining php

Comment: see the answer below then; I for one don't know what you're trying to do or what is used or intended to be used for the `<select>`'s.

Comment: for each select i request records from mysql, this is the code
  <?php
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT first_name5 FROM bank");
//$stmt = $pdo->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option >" . $row['first_name5'] . "</option>";
}
?>

Comment: i added image above to explain what i need  its containing tables with add row inputs, please help

Comment: this image explain what i need https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBl0c.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return $db->lastInsertId();` from `foreach` block.

It will return value after one iteration. That's the reason, only one value getting inserted and rest are not.

---

See, I found few mistakes, which I'm stating below. Follow it, It will work.

***Changes***

**1)** Give name here in this checkbox. `<td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="checkedCheckBox[]"/></td>`. And, name must be of array type. Because, on basis of this checkbox only, you are going to insert values  in table. Right?

**2)** Then, ID can't be same. You gave 4 input IDs as `first_name`, which is not right. Change all IDs to unique ones. **IDs must be unique.**

**3)** In **new-contract.php** page, find what are the checkbox checked through this line. `foreach ($_POST['checkedCheckBox'] as $key => $value)  {`. Here, `checkedCheckBox` is the name which I mentioned in **Point-1**.

**4)** In **new-contract.php** page, Remove `return $db->lastInsertId();` from the `foreach` statement. Otherwise, after Ist Iteration, code will exit and return Last Inserted ID.

---

***Updated Code***

**index.php**

```
<form action="new-contract.php" method="post">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead style="">
            <tr>
                <th class="check-this">
                    <input class="check_all" type="checkbox"  onclick="select_all()"/>
                </th>
                <th class="text-center"> م </th>
                <th class="text-center"> اسم الصنف </th>
                <th class="text-center"> الوحدة </th>
                <th class="text-center"> الكمية </th>
                <th class="text-center"> سعر الوحدة </th>
                <th class="text-center"> العام المالي </th>
                <th class="text-center"> إجمالي قيمة الصنف </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="checkedCheckBox[]"/></td>
            <td><span id="snum">1.</span></td>
            <td>
                <select class="select" id="first_name1" name="items[]">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="select" id="first_name2" name="units[]">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input class="select qty" type="number" id="tamil" name="qtys[]"/></td>
            <td><input class="select unit" type="number" id="english" name="unitno[]" /></td>
            <td>
                <select class="select " id="first_name3" name="financials[]">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="total" name="totals[]" class="amount" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input name="set-cont" type="submit" class="sb-btn center" value="حفظ"/>
</form>
```

**new-contract.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['set-cont'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['checkedCheckBox'] as $key => $value)  {
        $items = $_POST["items"][$key];
        $units = $_POST["units"][$key];
        $qtys = $_POST["qtys"][$key];
        $unitno = $_POST["unitno"][$key];
        $financials = $_POST["financials"][$key];
        $totals = $_POST["totals"][$key];
        try {
            $db = DB();
            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_contract (items, units, qtys, unitno, financials, totals) VALUES(:items,:units,:qtys,:unitno,:financials,:totals)");
            $query->bindParam("items", $items, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("units", $units, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("qtys", $qtys, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("unitno", $unitno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("financials", $financials, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $qQuery->bindParam("totals", $totals, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
           exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @peter : Please see my updated answer. It will solve your problem. I checked personally and modified few codes which I mentioned in my answer. Please have a look. And, respond me back.

Comment: thanks for replay, but didn't work ,i have update and ids changed any field have a unique id and checkbox input removed.. sorry didn't work only one row record not all

Comment: can we thought for another fix .. plaase help

Comment: No, It's not possible. I gave my working code which were entering very correctly @peter. Even though, wait for 15 minutes. I will reply for sure after cross checking.

Comment: okay, i know is somthing very tired i have 3days  searching for it and not found the solution.. im waiting for your answer

Comment: Hi @peter, whatever changes I told you to do. Can you please edit your question and updated the updated code. I wanted to check what you did with my code. Just for assurance. Don't mind. We are near to solution. Fast Peter.

Comment: No. You have not used my code. Literally. Please Man. It's very difficult to make people understand. I can't go and modify your code there itself. Why you removed first checkbox in each row? And, not using my code in submit page also. Please Man. If you want yourself tension free, please copy my whole code and modify only for `<select>`. I beg. Please @peter

Comment: i already used your code with checkbox input but same problem found one row record, this ccheck box used for delete row in javascript and its didn't in colum of mysql table

Comment: so i decided to remove it

Comment: you didn't know i using javascript to add rows dynamicly for tr in table